# Altair: Last bars are overhanging the axis

Tags: data-visualization, altair

I want to achieve:

- Thicker bar sizes (e.g. size=30)
- x-axis scale between 0-1
- Enough space between the last bar to not overlap the y-axis without having an additional tick on the x-axis

My problem so far:

```
alt.Chart(feature_score_df[0]).mark_bar(color='darkred', size=30).encode(
    x=alt.X(
        'feature_score:Q',
        scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0.05,0.95)),
        axis=alt.Axis(title='Feature Score')),
    y=alt.Y('count:Q', axis=alt.Axis(title='Account Count')),
    tooltip=alt.Tooltip(['feature_score', 'count'])
)
```

[image]

I tried setting `clip=True` but then the outside bars just get cut in half:
[image]

Applying `width=alt.Step(100)` doesn't change the graph. I guess it has to do with `domain` property set.
Setting the `width` explicitly in the `properties` makes the graph wider but doesn't help  with the overhang problem:
[image]

Any ideas would be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the data type of `feature_score` to ordinal: `feature_score:O` and dropping the scale domain fixed the issue.